# Importing FBX with camera & target placeholders

Tags: python, camera, import, .fbx

I am importing FBX files that have camera placeholders.  They will import as Empty's in blender that may have useful animation.  I want to add add a camera to each as a child (inherit animation) and align the view to the placeholder's alignment, parent it, and add a TRACK_TO constraint if there is a "cameraName.Target" Empty placeholder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is an example script that worked for me.  I first (manually) created a collection named "cameras" and moved all the Empties into that collection.  I skip any existing cameras in case I run the script more than once.

````
import bpy

for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    hasACamera = False
    if ( ("Camera" in obj.name) and ("Target" not in obj.name) and (obj.type != 'CAMERA') ):
        for child in obj.children:
            if (child.type == 'CAMERA'):
                hasACamera = True
        if ( hasACamera is True ):
            print( obj.name + ": already has a camera")
            continue
        print( obj )
        print( obj.type )
        bpy.ops.object.camera_add()
        bpy.context.object.name = obj.name + ".Camera"
        print( bpy.context.object )
        print( bpy.context.active_object )
        sel = bpy.data.objects[bpy.context.object.name]
        print( sel.name + " align"  )
        bpy.ops.transform.transform(mode='ALIGN', value=(0, 0, 0, 0), orient_type='GLOBAL',
         orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=False,
         proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)
        sel.parent = obj
        bpy.ops.object.collection_link(collection='cameras')
    if ( (obj.type == 'CAMERA') and (".Camera" in obj.name) ):
        targetName = obj.name[0:-7] + ".Target"
        try:
            targetObj = bpy.data.objects[targetName]
            if obj.constraints["Track To"] is None:
                print( "adding Track To constraint" )
                obj.constraints.new(type='TRACK_TO')
                obj.constraints["Track To"].target = targetObj
        except:
            print()
```
````